# VLANs isolating networks (VoIP/Wi-Fi)

Tags: switch, router, vlan, ethernet, voip

I have to set up our network in our new office. I'm no networking expert (developer), but I need some input and advice here for some things I wonder about.

I have purchased the following:

- 2 x Cisco CS200 smart-switch 24p
- 1 x VoIP PBX (VoIP + 4 access points)
- 1 x dual LAN router
- 4 x 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi access points (Wi-F1 1)
- 2 x 5 GHz access points (Wi-Fi 2)

Connected like this:

- Switch 1 (link port) is connected to the router
- Switch 2 (link port) is connected to Switch 1 (standard port)
- PBX/access points and Wi-Fi are all connected to the switches

My questions are about the networking itself:

- Am I killing the speed connecting SW1->SW2 through a regular port? Should I get a SFP cable, or does that not matter for this size of network?
- Would it be smarter to connect SW2 directly to the router instead of to SW1?

The other questions I have are about (probably) VLANs:

- I would like to isolate the PBX/VoIP part, and prioritize traffic from this. The Cisco switches have some options for this, I think, but would this be smart to set a VLAN to those only, or is it overkill? Any directions to how I can do this? The most important thing is that the phone system gets highest priority on the network, and I don't want/need the people to be able to access it.
- I would like Wi-Fi 1 to be the primary network (a VLAN for this too?). Wi-Fi 2 is thought of as an extra fast network for our developers, with very few limitations, but I would like this network to be able to see the primary network (Wi-Fi 1), but I don't want Wi-Fi 1 to be able to see Wi-Fi 2. Can this be done?

The last question is very basic about VLANs. Am I correct in the understanding that the VLAN has to flow from the router? As the switches are not layer-3, so the router has to control the VLAN, right?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had a look at the cs200 switch from the documentation found at http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/small-business-200-series-smart-switches/data_sheet_c78-634369.html

It appears the CS200 switch doesn't support routing. You will have to create a trunk port from switch1 to the router while on the router connected to switch1, create what is known as router-on-a-stick.

See http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/336-cisco-router-8021q-router-stick.html

My 2 cents for your network implementation, wifi (currently half-duplex csma-ca) is a convenience that is great for mobile users. If you want reliability, stability and performance for your workers, you really should consider wired connectivity (full duplex) as primary.

Answer (score 1):

- your do not need to connect the SFP ports, you getting the same performance with the normal port.
- I do not find as per your description any difference between SW1 and SW2, so there is no difference
- It is preferred to configure the Voice VLAN and the configuration will depend on if you will connect the users to the LAN port on the IP phone.
  -for your last question, yes you can control the traffic between Wifi 1 and wifi 2 by configuring access lists on the router